# How to use/install merge method for data.sets from memisc package?

Tags: r, methods, merge

I have two data.sets (from the `memisc` package) all set for merge, and the merge goes through without error or warning, but the output is a data.frame, not a data.set. The command is:

```
datTS <- merge(datT1, datT2, by.x="ryear", by.y="ryear")
```

(Sorry I don't have a more convenient example with toy data handy.) The following pages seem to make it very clear that there should be a method built into `memisc` that properly merges the data.sets into one data.set:

http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/rforge/memisc/man/dataset-manip.html
https://github.com/melff/memisc/blob/master/pkg/R/dataset-methods.R

...but it just doesn't seem to be properly triggering on my machine (sorry also for my clumsy lingo). Note the similarity of my code and the example code from the very end of the first page I linked:

```
ds6 <- merge(ds1,ds5,by.x="a",by.y="c")
```

I've verified that I have the most recent versions of R, RStudio, `memisc`, and all dependencies. I've used a number of other `memisc` methods so far (`within`, `transform`, `missing.values`, etc.) without issue.

So my question is: what else does one need to do to get the `merge` function to properly produce a data.set when the source data are in data.set form, as per the `memisc` package? (There's no explicit addressing of this merge capability in the official package documentation.) Since the code in the second link above seems to provide the method for this, is there some workaround, at least, for installing and utilizing that code? Maybe there's just some separate "methods installation" I'm not aware of (but why would it be separate from the main package?).

Comment: The help page for pkg:memisc in the released version 0.97 does not describe a merge function method for `data.set`s. You are pointing us to the github version which may not be the one that has been released. Did you install the github version?

Comment: That explains it. I just looked around in that github parent directly and saw the readme where it explains that pre-release versions of `memisc` are posted there. That fully answers my question. Post it as an answer if you want and I'll hit accept. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The help page for pkg:memisc in the released version 0.97 does not describe a merge function method for data.sets. You are pointing us to the github version which may not be the one that has been released. You need to install the github version.  See: https://github.com/melff/memisc/releases